# Migrating existing site to Azure is slow

Tags: hosting, virtual-hosts

I am migrating a site to Azure. However the site is now running unacceptably slow. The setup is as follows:

- Azure standard Linux apps service plan
- MySQL on Azure standard instance

Here's some of the things I've tried:

- Increasing the size of the web VM
- Increasing the size of the database VM
- Disabling output buffering
- Enabling wordpress query caches and viewing database response times
- Disabling Azure VM affinity routing
- Disabling response buffering
- Disabling all plugins
- Testing database performance (I wrote a simple page to time the response for a simple query, this page claims to take .001-.002 seconds to render, but TTFB reported by Chrome is around 2.7 seconds).

To give you an idea of the sense of the scale of the problem the current live site loads in around 1 second, the Azure version loads in about 10 seconds.

Does anyone have any advice or suggestions as to what I should look at next?

Comment: This question is not specific to WordPress, you'll have much better luck in one of [the recommended support forums](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/community/), such as StackOverflow or Serverfault

Comment: I agree with @Kero you'll get better answers on the other sites, it more likely than not is due to the server, have you any idea if the Azure server is running apache or nginx - that information maybe useful for the guys over at the SF/ SO sites.

Comment: I've posted it on server fault. It is using apache. @Aravona